# Rails: Could not find 'nokogiri' on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri

I have recently tried to download the 'Nokogiri' gem in rails (on Windows 10 OS) with the following command.

```
gem install nokogiri
```

And I received the following error.

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri/2.2/nokogiri.so
```

Then when the installation was unsuccessful I tried inserting the following line into my Gemfile

```
gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.6', '>= 1.6.6.2'
```

This was also unsuccessful

however even after I have removed `gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.6', '>= 1.6.6.2'` from the Gemfile I still receive the same error?

After receiving this error I also have not been able to do anything else in rails eg:
now when I try to start a new rails project I get the following error

```
    C:\Sites>rails new app
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:308:in `to_specs': Could not find 'nokogiri' (>= 1.5.9) among 200 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
...
```

running `bundle` gives me the following error

```
   Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri/2.2/nokogiri.so

...

An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.8), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.8'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I have tried using

```
 gem install nokogiri --prerelease
```

I have tried

```
gem uninstall nokogiri
```

I have also tried

```
-Source "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=230477"
```

How do I fix this issue or revert back to rails before I had these issues?

I have looked everywhere and I can't find an effective solution to this.
If there is any more information you require about this please ask in the comments and I'll do my best to give an informative answer.

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to install the gem `gem install nokogiri` . If yes try open `irb` and `require 'nokogiry'`

Comment: I am not able to use `gem install nokogiri` and I get a Permission denied error like in the question above

Comment: Maybe you should launch your cmd as administrator. I know that `C` drive in most windows computers is considered as system disk and restricts permissions for users.